# .net MVC passing linq data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I am trying to pass data from controller to view. I have searched the web but could not find a solution.

if I do this it works:

Controller:

```
var yyy = (from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select a) ;
ViewBag.data = yyy;
```

View:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.data)
{
    @item.Value
}
```

But the following code does not work:

Controller:

```
var yyy = (from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select new {Value = a.Value, TypeCode = a.TypeCode, Return = Calculate(a.Return)}) ;
ViewBag.data = yyy;
```

View:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.data)
{
    @item.Value
}
```

It gives "item does not contain a definition for Value" for the view file.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

-edited: updated the second controller linq query. and corrected the first controller linq query.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why your *first* code works. That looks like it's displaying `a.Value.Value` for each `a`.

Comment: @justin you are right, first code does not work. updating now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because You already select `Value` and `Value` has no such property as `Value`. You should change in controller:

`var yyy = (from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select a.Value);` to

```
var yyy = (from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select a);
```

**OR** change the view to

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.data)
{
    @item
}
```

**//////////////////////////////////////////////// EDITS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////**
Than You should not use anonymous object. You should create `ViewModelClass`. For Example:

```
public class AuthoritiesViewModel
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string TypeCode { get; set; }
            public string Return { get; set; }
        }
```

And change your controller:

```
var yyy = (from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select new AuthoritiesViewModel{ Value = a.Value, TypeCode = a.TypeCode, Return = Calculate(a.Return)});
ViewBag.data = yyy;
```

and in your view you will be able to use:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>Value</th>
         <th>TypeCode</th>
         <th>Return</th>
    </tr>
@foreach(AuthoritiesViewModel item in ViewBag.data)
{
    <tr>
         <td>@item.Value<td>
         <td>@item.TypeCode<td>
         <td>@item.Return<td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Also, I have a question to You. Why do You use `ViewBag` to pass data from controller to view? Why don't You use Model to pass these data to view according to MVC pattern?

**//////////////////////////////////////////////// MORE EDITS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////**
To send more than one query result You can create more complex model. For example:

```
public class AuthoritiesViewModel
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string TypeCode { get; set; }
            public string Return { get; set; }
        }

        public class AnotherQueryViewModel
        {
            public string AnotherQueryValue { get; set; }
            public string AnotherQueryTypeCode { get; set; }
            public string AnotherQueryReturn { get; set; }
        }

        public class ModelClass
        {
            IEnumerable<AuthoritiesViewModel> Authorities { get; set; }
            IEnumerable<AnotherQueryViewModel> AnotherQueryResults { get; set; }
        }
```

And change the controller:

```
var yyy = (from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select new AuthoritiesViewModel{ Value = a.Value, TypeCode = a.TypeCode, Return = Calculate(a.Return)});

// do your another select
var zzz = (from smthing select new AnotherQueryViewModel ...)

// create model instance
ModelClass model = new ModelClass() 
{
    Authorities = yyy.AsEnumerable(),
    AnotherQueryResults = zzz..AsEnumerable()
}

// return view with model
return View("view", model);
```

and in view you can use:

```
@model ModelClass

@*display first query result*@
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>Value</th>
         <th>TypeCode</th>
         <th>Return</th>
    </tr>
@foreach(AuthoritiesViewModel item in Model.Authorities)
{
    <tr>
         <td>@item.Value<td>
         <td>@item.TypeCode<td>
         <td>@item.Return<td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

@*display second query result*@
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>Another Query Value</th>
         <th>Another Query TypeCode</th>
         <th>Another Query Return</th>
    </tr>
@foreach(AnotherQueryViewModel item in Model.AnotherQueryResults)
{
    <tr>
         <td>@item.AnotherQueryValue<td>
         <td>@item.AnotherQueryTypeCode<td>
         <td>@item.AnotherQueryReturn<td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Actually I want to write the following linq query, select more than 1 field:

from a in Connection.Db.Authorities select new { Value = a.Value, TypeCode = a.TypeCode, Return = Calculate(a.Return) }

Comment: Yes Dmytro, you are right, it works now. Thank you a lot... The problem is, as you have said, I should create a viewmodelclass. And, as an answer to your question, I want to send more than one query result to view, so I am using ViewBag instead of Model.

Comment: @isa, To send more than one query result You can create more complex model. For example see my more edits.

Comment: this is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you very much. You clearly defined everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

**use sth like this**

ViewBag.qualification = new SelectList(db.Lookups.Where(x => x.lookup_type == "Qualification"), "lookup_content", "lookup_content");