# Returning Linq value in controller and passing it to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Having a problem returning and passing the desired values to the View. I run the LINQ query in LINQPad4 and it returns the correct results. I feel I'm missing something simple here. I've using this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793767/net-mvc-passing-linq-data-from-controller-to-view) as a reference

Im getting the

> CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)ERROR.
>   \

When I run and step through the code i dont see any values and the message I'm given is

> Message = "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

**UPDATE**

Changing the View from `@model IEnumerable<Login.Models.EditProfile>` to `@model Login.Models.EditProfile` Helped with the CS1061 Error I was having and as for the LINQ query not working please look at the accepted answer below by Titian.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Let me know If there is more information I can provide.

/ **Controller** /

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {


        using (TDBEntities db1 = new TDBEntities())
        {
            var user =  (from a in db1.ExternalUsers
                        join b in db1.ExternalUserEmails on a.ExternalUserID equals b.ExternalUserID
                        join c in db1.ExternalUserPhones on a.ExternalUserID equals c.ExternalUserID
                        where a.ExternalUserID.Equals(id)
                        select new EditProfile {ExternalUserID = a.ExternalUserID, FirstName = a.FirstName, LastName = a.LastName, EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress, PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber });

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

            return View(user);
        }
    }
```

/**Model**/

```
    public partial class EditProfile
    {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
      public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
      public int ExternalUserID { get; set; }

    }
```

/**View**/

```
@model IEnumerable<Login.Models.EditProfile>
@using Login.Helpers

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Update Employee";
 }

 <h2></h2>

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Update Employee</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "Email Address:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "Phone Number:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="resetPw control-label col-md-2 ">Reset Password</label>            
        <div> @Html.CheckBox("ResetPassword", false, new { @style = "margin: 10px 15px 0;" }) <i>(check to reset)</i></div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Comment: If you are editing a single record, your view should be strongly typed to `@model Login.Models.EditProfile`. Also you need to send a single object form the action method to view, not a collection. Use `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a `FirstOrDefault` to your query. Select will return a value (of type `IQueryable<User>`) even if there are no values (an empty result). You actually want the first value in that result or null if there are no matching results:

```
        var user =  (from a in db1.ExternalUsers
                    join b in db1.ExternalUserEmails on a.ExternalUserID equals b.ExternalUserID
                    join c in db1.ExternalUserPhones on a.ExternalUserID equals c.ExternalUserID
                    where a.ExternalUserID == id
                    select new EditProfile {ExternalUserID = a.ExternalUserID, FirstName = a.FirstName, LastName = a.LastName, EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress, PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: When I add `.FirstOrDefault();` I get System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Comment: Use `==` instead of `Equals` for id equality